# Wordlist generator from dictionary

Tags: linux, unix, sed, grep

I've seen awesome wordlist generators like crunch, but all of them start from scratch, any idea how can I generate wordlists that use a base dictionary file and then extrapolate those words by adding numbers, uppercase letters, etc. ?

I remember John the ripper had the ability to do this, but only when cracking, it didn't work to generate wordfiles.

Example:

```
[root@www ~]# cat test.txt 
John
Julia
```

Output:

```
[root@www ~]# cat testprocessed.txt 
John0001
John0002
John3553
juliA
Julia9857
```

and as many permutations as possible..

Thanks :)

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 1):

John 1.8.0 works just fine on my system:

```
$ cat test.txt
John
Julia

$ john --wordlist=test.txt --rules --stdout > testprocessed.txt
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
102p 0:00:00:00 100% 3400p/s Juliing

$ head testprocessed.txt
John
Julia
john
julia
johns
julias
john1
julia1
John1
Julia1
```

I suggest you instead look into why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the --stdout option, I guess this is a good start, if anyone knows another wordlist generator that does this it will be welcome :)